# Cross Account S3 Access for a public buket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

Bucket Policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1589032691178",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1589032265458",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<BUCKET>/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

This will allow read objects to all user.

IAM Policy attached to user ABC in AWS Account 1

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<BUCKET>"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<BUCKET>/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

With this setup public read of objects is there to anyone

And IAM policy is attached to user ABC, so ABC has access to list, put, get, delete

Now the question is
If someone in AWS Account 2 creates a user XYZ and attached same IAM policy as above
Will the XYZ user in AWS Account 2 be able to list, get, put, delete  ?

Comment: No, of course not. If the access is granted, imagine you can access any resource on AWS if you know the ARN of it. That would be terribly BAD. See Milan's answer below.

Comment: Cross-account policy evaluation logic is explained [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_evaluation-logic-cross-account.html). Long story short, you need both sides (i.e. the resource AND the principle) to say YES.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you posted looks like `resource-based & IAM policies` cross account access.

In order to allow user XYZ in account 2 to execute mentioned actions on bucket in account 1, apart from policy you specified for user XYZ, you need to additionally specify allowed actions for user XYZ in bucket's policy.

Alternative way is to allow cross-account IAM role assumption, where user in account 2 can assume role in account 1 granting desired access to the S3 bucket in account 1.

More information with examples can be found at https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cross-account-access-s3/

Comment: What's the benefit to use assume role as oppose to the first approach?

Comment: @jellycsc role assumption might be more beneficial e.g. when you need to allow access to multiple of your S3 buckets. Then you don't need to modify bucket policy for each bucket separately, but rather you modify only single policy allowing operation on multiple buckets. Furthermore, on some AWS services, it is not possible to configure resource-based policies and thus only role assumption option is available for cross account access.